# ServiceStack CsvSerializer date format

Tags: servicestack, export-to-csv

Using CsvSerializer as a static class. All of my dates are being output with the UTC Offset:

```
2017-09-05T01:51:52-07:00
```

The dates being fed in are UTC, I want the offset removed, so the output would be

```
2017-09-05T01:51:52
```

Code is being called as

```
CsvSerializer.SerializeToStream(data, outputStream);
```

I have tried using the following JsConfig settings with no luck:

```
JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.DCJSCompatible;
JsConfig.AssumeUtc = true;
JsConfig.AppendUtcOffset = false;
```

Maybe I'm just using them incorrectly? 
How can I use the static CsvSerializer and get the dates output in the format I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override how Date's are serialized with:

```
JsConfig<DateTime>.SerializeFn = date => date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```